# Laravel returns "Incorrect datetime value" on update

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

For reasons unknown our Laravel 5.5 installation fails on all updates where the date starts with "2018-03-25".

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-25 03:00:00' for column 'done_date' at row 1 (SQL: update `hours` set `done_date` = 2018-03-25 03:00:00, `updated_at` = 2018-05-31 12:19:36 where `id` = 481)
```

All other datetimes are fine.

Here's the table syntax:

`CREATE TABLE hours (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  task_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  project_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  done_hours double(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  done_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  info text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  archived_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  deleted_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=906 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

What could cause this?

Comment: According to the docs this error is thrown if one supplies a bad datetime format - anything else than `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, but yours seems alright. Very weird indeed.

Comment: `'2018-03-25 03:00:00'` might be invalid for the servers time zone due to *daylight saving time shift*.

Comment: insert your code

Comment: Paul Spiegel might be right about the time shift. I'll get the easy way and just replace all of those problematic timestamps.